# Invertible matrix properties of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have here the following question:

> Let $X$ be the $5 \times 5$ matrix "full of ones":
>
> $X = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$
>
> $(a)$ Is $X$ invertible? Explain.
>
> $(b)$ Find a number $c$ such that $X^2=cX$.
>
> $(c)$ Compute $(X-aI_5)(X+(a-c)I_5)$, where $a$ is a real number, $c$ is the constant from part $(b)$, $a\neq 0$, and $a\neq c$. If $M=(X-aI_5)$, what is $M^{-1}$? (You may express your answer in terms of $X,I_5,a$, and $c.$)

I already did part $(a)$ and $(b)$.

$(a)$ No. It's not invertible since there are two or more identical rows or columns so the determinant would be $0$ and hence it is not invertible.

$(b)$ $X^2 = \begin{pmatrix}5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\\ 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$

Thus, $c=5$.

$(c)$ I almost got part $(c)$ too. It's the last part I can't figure out.

$=(X-aI_5)(X+(a-c)I_5)$

$=-a(a-c)I_5$

If $M=(X-aI_5)$, that would mean if I multiply both sides by $(X+(a-c)I_5)$, I get that:

$$M(X+(a-c)I_5)=(X-aI_5)(X+(a-c)I_5)$$
$$M(X+(a-c)I_5)=-a(a-c)I_5$$

I can literally see the answer in front of me, but it's not quite there. How do I proceed from here?

For reference, the answer should be:

$M^{-1}=\frac{X+(a-c)I_5}{-a(a-c)}$

Comment: HINT:$MM^{-1}=M^{-1}M=I $.

Comment: Yes I know that but how does that help? My problem is that I need to divide what are essentially matrices, and I don't think that's allowed.

Comment: Note that  $-a(a-c) \in \Bbb R  $.

Comment: Yep. I notice that too but what about the fact that I am multiplying it with identity? if I divide, don't I also have to take the identity matrix into account?

Comment: Never mind I get it! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just divide the whole equation by the scalar and compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You have $M(X+(a-c)I_5)=-a(a-c)I_5$. Pre-multiply by $M^{-1}$.